an LC low pass filter for a peizo actuator
I have a piezo actuator with capacitance of 2.5uF, I was wondering if I can consider this actuator as a capacitor for a PI LC low pass filter, then I can couple it with my switching stage and have it turn into a class D amplifier to drive the actuator.  so I go and try to figure out what L value I need to get a cutoff of 500 Hz (max frequency the piezo will be seeing). It says the L value is 33 Henries, pretty awful. Can I add more stages or something so I can get the L value to be lower ?

@glen_geek interesting idea, but this is meant for haptic use so cavities are not possible. The skin itself acts as a low pass filter with a cutoff around 300 Hz( i mentioned 500 hz since it's still detectable), but the thing is this is with regard to how haptic vibrational perception is sensed by our bodies, not sure if the filtering is grounded in physics to have it demodulate PWM from class D switching stage. Does it need to be? still worth checking out though

I mean grounded in physics versus bio-sensory perception

Can you provide a complex impedance plot and table of data (preferably GB) versus frequency? Piezo transducers can be considered capacitors below resonance, but the impedance strays from a capacitor to a more complex equivalence as you approach resonance and higher.

@qrk yeah the data on this is very limited : https://datasheet.octopart.com/Z63000Z2910Z1Z43-TDK-datasheet-140091427.pdf
the resonance is 15k, I only intend  to drive it at 500 hz max, would it be safe it just model this as a capacitor ?

Since the resonance is 30x higher than the operational frequency, treating the transducer impedance as a capacitor is reasonable, even at 1 kHz to 2 kHz where you may want to put your corner freq if you're using a class-D amplifier. If the inductor is too large, you can put extra capacitance across the transducer. It would be a good idea to buy one of these transducers and get complex impedance data so you can simulate what's happening.
